# using Lookback API how to find tasks that did not have a change in ToDo?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I am writing an app that shows a  grid of tasks, filtered by iteration, where ToDo has not been modified within certain time frame. Per documentation Iterations on Tasks are not available in LookbackAPI, but there is a second question: how to find tasks that did not have a change in ToDo within a time period specified? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply this filter

```
"_PreviousValues.ToDo":{$exists: false}
```

to get snapshots where ToDo was not modified.

This query looks for Tasks in a specific project, and limit the time frame:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/1111/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_ProjectHierarchy":2222,"_TypeHierarchy":"Task","_PreviousValues.ToDo":{$exists: false},_ValidFrom:{$gte: "2014-04-XXTxx:xx:00.000Z",$lt: "2014-04-XXTxx:yy:00.000Z"}}&fields=["_UnformattedID","ToDo","_PreviousValues.ToDo"]
```

A slightly different `"_PreviousValues.ToDo":null` returns the task's first snapshot that corresponds to the original revision when ToDo was not set in addition to the same snapshots returned when filtered by `"_PreviousValues.ToDo":{$exists: false}`

As far as filtering tasks by iteration, you may use `Rally.data.wsapi.Store` to get ObjectIDs of the tasks filtered by iteration, and then `Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore` filtered by the array of OIDs

```
{
     property: 'ObjectID',
     operator: 'in',
     value: arr
}
```

where arr is [123456789, 987654321,...]